# Unable to parse data from database with locale data

Tags: javascript, contentful, content-management

I am relatively new to React but I was previously working with the Contentful delivery API and decided to switch to the Content Management API because it better suited my needs. Now when I import all of the fields in my entries they all have what appears to be a locale in front of them. This is what it looks like: `{en-US: "textile"}` and here is a screenshot of it in the console of the browser:

[Screenshot of console output from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWLzI.png)

I'm sure it is a pretty simple fix but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to parse this data and I have been unable to find any help on the Internet. Could someone please help me out, I just want the text that I was able to originally get so easily with the delivery API.

Comment: Heyo, Contentful DevRel here. :) Be aware that if you use the Content Management API the requests are not cached via a CDN and, more importantly, if you use it directly in your React app you're exposing your CMA token which has the same access rights as the logged in user who created it. People could enter/edit/change your data when they discover that.

Comment: @stefanjuudis If I am using the OAuth 2.0 access tokens is this still a problem?

Comment: The write access depends on how you do it (there is a read only way as I see). https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/oauth/#creating-an-oauth-2-0-application The fact that for public usage the CDA is the way to go remains, though, because in case you generate a lot of traffic the requests should hit a CDN and it's faster, too. :) Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping there is going to be only one key 'en-us' inside each object

```js
var industry = {'en-us':'textile'};
var featured = {'en-us':true};

var dbData= {industry,featured};
var newData = {}

//iterate and extract the values to newData

Object.keys(dbData).forEach(key=>{
  newData[key] = Object.values(dbData[key])[0]
})


console.log(newData)
```